# Which slide toggle is the most efficient for mobile phone websites?

Tags: javascript, css, slidetoggle, mobile-phones

My problem is that I want to use a slide toggle that will give the absolute best performance on mobile phones (no flickering, no glitches, no stops, no performance loss) using hardware acceleration, if possible.

The best solution until now that I've found is this one:

```
$(elementToDisplay).slideToggle("fast", "linear");
```

Yes I know you will say ... jQuery slideToggle???!!! But until now this is the best approach for me without creating it from scratch, and of course you know creating it from scratch works until a certain point when the complexity becomes to big.

Can someone help me? Maybe there is a crazy programmer who created a slide toggle that works absolutely flawless on mobiles phones.

Maybe some of you can point out something.

Thank you in advance,

Adrian

Comment: This should get some more attention.